# Pagination loop with offset 100

Tags: python, api, pagination

I am working on a code where I am fetching records from an API and this API has pagination implemented on it where it would allow maximum of 100 records. So I have to loop in the multiples of 100's. Currently my code compares the total records and loops from *offset* 100 and then 101,102,103 etc. I want it to loop in 100's(like 100,200,300) and stop as soon as the offset is greater than the total records. I am not sure how to do this, i have partial code which increment by 1 instead of 100 and wont stop when needed. Could anyone please help me with this issue.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

#Token for Authorization
API_ACCESS_KEY = 'Token'
Accept='application/xml'

#Query Details that is passed in the URL
since = '2018-01-01'
until = '2018-02-01'
limit = '100'
offset = '0'
total = 'true'

def get():

    url_address = "https://mywebsite/web?offset="+str('0') 
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'token={0}'.format(API_ACCESS_KEY),
        'Accept': Accept,
    }
    querystring = {"since":since,"until":until, "limit":limit, "total":total}


    # find out total number of pages
    r = requests.get(url=url_address, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()
    total_record = int(r['total'])
    print("Total record: " +str(total_record))

    # results will be appended to this list
    all_items = []

    # loop through all offset and return JSON object
    for offset in range(0, total_record):

        url = "https://mywebsite/web?offset="+str(offset)              
        response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()        
        all_items.append(response)       
        offset = offset + 100
        print(offset)

    # prettify JSON
    data = json.dumps(all_items, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

    return data

print(get())
```

Currently when I print the offset I see
Total Records: 345
100,
101,
102,

Expected:
Total Records: 345
100,
200,
300
Stop the loop!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way you could do it is change

```
for offset in range(0, total_record):
    url = "https://mywebsite/web?offset="+str(offset)              
    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()        
    all_items.append(response)       
    offset = offset + 100
    print(offset)
```

to

```
for offset in range(0, total_record, 100):
    url = "https://mywebsite/web?offset="+str(offset)              
    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()        
    all_items.append(response)       
    print(offset)
```

as you cannot change offset inside the loop

Comment: Amazing Thank you soo much @dangee1705 it worked like a charm had not issue. It stopped as soon as it reached 300.  I have one last question how do I put all the results into a data frame? I know the results are appended in all_items.

Answer (score 1):

## loop through all offset and return JSON object

```
for offset in range(0,total_record,100):

    url = "https://mywebsite/web?offset="+str(offset)              
    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()        
    all_items.append(response)       
    print(offset)
```

Comment: this doesnt work, you cannot modify offset inside the loop

Comment: Yes Shivangi I tried your solution of changing in the offset it worked but it did not stop the loop.

Comment: Sorry about that I missed the second part of your question. Try the new code

Comment: No worries, the new code worked, I have one last question if possible please help how do I put all the results into a data frame? I know all the records(345) are appended in all_items but how do i transfer it to a data frame

Comment: You can do that using pandas

Comment: Got it, Thank you (y)